# Loopback: Creating relations between models in different microservices

Tags: node.js, microservices, loopbackjs

We have different microservices running on different instances and all the models are created using `Loopback 3.x`.

I am able to achieve relations when the models are defined in the same service easily. I'm confused about how to create relations (`hasOne`, `hasMany` etc.) between models when the models are present in different services.

Comment: I would say that this is not possible. You should save the ids inside the model of the one service and resolve the objects by querying the API of the other service. The idea behind the microservice is that one service should not know and rely on the inside of an other service

Comment: Exactly - your Order model doesn't have a Customer, it has a Customer ID.

Comment: Oh okay, sounds good. I already do have the foreign keys stored, will just need to resolve the objects during the API calls. Thanks!